# How to disable ActiveMQ client jar dependency

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am publishing the JMS message using ActiveMQ. When I am using below code then it is compiling properly with two Jars(activemq-client.jar and geronimo-jms_1.1_spec.jar):

```
Connection connection = null;
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new 
ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Topic topic = session.createTopic("customerTopic");

connection.start();

String payload = "Important task";
Message msg = session.createTextMessage(payload);
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);
producer.send(msg);
Thread.sleep(3000);
session.close();
connection.close();
```

However, at runtime it is giving error to include all the dependency jars. It is working fine while adding all the dependency jars. but I do not want to add these dependency jars(around 17MB)

Is there any way to disable the jars dependency for ActiveMQ client application?

Comment: So you expect your code to magically work without all the supporting code that makes it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile-time and Run-time dependencies are oftentimes different as the requirements of compiling code vs. actually running it are different. If there is a run-time dependency you can't simply get rid of it or the application won't run properly (or at all). "Dependencies" are dependencies for a reason; the application *depends* on them.